How does adding twist to an elliptical distribution alter induced drag? Effect of twist on induced drag
I have been thinking about this for the past few days, and I still cannot get my head around it. So, I know that for a given span, an elliptical circulation distribution will produce the least induced drag due to the constant downwash. However, what if you add washout to a wing which has an elliptical circulation distribution, will induced drag be decreased further?
Downwash wont be constant and your circulation distribution wont be elliptical anymore, but wont downwash be reduced as essentially you are reducing your local lift coefficient compared to the non-twist case?
Like for example, lets say we have a rectangular wing with a lot of wash-in starting from the root towards the tip, and now lets compare it to a rectangular wing with a lot of wash-out starting form the root, like the image below. Which one would have the least amount of induced drag? like can you tell which kind of lift distribution will have lesser amount of induced drag by simply looking at the distribution? I have drawn the examples below:


Shown above is an example of a wing with a lot of wash-out starting form the 'root' aka centre.
If you could help me understand this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Like I am just confused about how to tell what kind of wing has more or less induced drag. Like in the example of the circulation distribution curves I drew, you can see there is an extreme case with lots of washout for a rectangular wing, and an extreme case with lots of washin. which one of these would produce less induced drag?
And is it correct to assume they both produce more induced drag than elliptical because they are not an elliptical distribution?

Induced drag happens when there is a gradient of circulation over span. An infinite wing, where circulation is constant over span, has no induced drag. The higher the gradient, the more the resulting vector of aerodynamic forces is tilted backwards. The higher the circulation, the higher the lift and, consequently, the backward component of aerodynamic forces.
This means you should have a shallow gradient where circulation is high and can progressively steepen the gradient when circulation decreases in order to minimize the backward component of aerodynamic forces, a.k.a. induced drag. That is what an elliptical circulation distribution over span achieves.
The one undisputed advantage of an unswept elliptical planform without washout is an elliptical lift distribution over the full angle of attack range with fully attached airflow. As soon as separation starts, however, that is no longer true. All other planforms need to be tweaked to produce an elliptical lift distribution and then do it only at one angle of attack. This tweaking is done by applying washout.
Ergo, an elliptical wing does not need washout, but when it is applied, induced drag will go up relative to lift.

Ok gotcha, so pretty much you need to try match the elliptical distribution at all points along the span to reduce induced drag. Is it possible to tell which kind of platform produces more or less induced drag relative to eachother? Like in the photo I drew of the rectangular wing with heaps of washout vs washin, how do I know which of these configurations has less induced drag?

@aerokid95 At what angle of attack? Without knowing this, no answer is possible. If you know incidence and airfoi over spanl, do a lifting line calculation. That should be the easiest way to find out.

Like if we assume linear twist from 0 -> +10 degrees for wash-in and -10 degrees for washout. I always thought washout would lower induced drag more than wash-in, because it reduces tip-loading which in my head I thought would help with minimising induced drag…. (Like how modern aircraft run tapered wings). Also, do you have any resources or links that are showing both how circulation and the gradient of circulation vary for different platforms? I would love to visualise this

@aerokid95 Oh, come on. I should not only do the thinking for you, but now also the research? Please grow up.

Sorry! I didn‘t mean to come across like that. I tried searching about circulation gradient over a wing but could not find anything online (only pressure gradient) so I just thought I would ask. Maybe I’m not using the right keywords or whatever. But thanks anyway

@aerokid95 Take a lifting line code and play around with it. This will be much better than any dry explanation.

Everywhere the lift along the span of the wing changes, a vortex is shed perpendicular to the trailing edge that contributes to the formation of a so-called vortex sheet. Well behind the wing, this vortex sheet rolls up into two big vortices that eventually dissipate due to the viscosity of the air. The following picture (from Wikipedia) nicely depicts some of those vortices which roll up behind the wing and the tailplane:

The vortex-sheet is responsible for the generation of a drag component which is termed "induced drag". It can be demonstrated that the induced drag reaches a minimum when the spanwise lift distribution is elliptical; in any other case the induced drag is bigger. In this case of elliptical lift distribution it exists a simple mathematical relation between lift and drag coefficients which is the well known $C_{d_i}  = C^2_l/\pi AR$.
Tweaking twist (aka washout), taper and airfoil shape along the span is how the spanwise lift distribution is modified in order to get as close to the ideal elliptical lift distribution as possible. Unless you have a wing with an elliptical platform, this tweaking is anyway valid only for a small range of AoA.

what if you add washout to a wing which has an elliptical circulation distribution, will induced drag be decreased further?

No, for the simple reason that if you have a washout distribution that already minimizes the induced drag then any modification to it will simply increase the induced drag - by definition of minimum.

can you tell which kind of lift distribution will have lesser amount of induced drag by simply looking at the distribution?

Yes, the elliptical one.
